# Limpiar tabla de jquery para mostrar otra informacion

Tags: jquery, ajax

tengo unos select, donde al elegir una opcion se carga la tabla con la respectva informacion, y de primera si muestra los datos, pero si escojo otra opcion del mismo select, si me trae los datos pero no los muestra se siguen mostrando los datos de la primera opcion, como puedo limpiar la tabla y dar paso a otra informacion en la tabla y asi cada vez que se elija diferente opcion del select

```
function CargarTabla() {

    var sucursal = document.getElementById('id').value;

    var datos = { tex: id };
    console.log(datos);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/information?id=' + id,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
        .done(function (list) {
       

            console.log("lista",list);

            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {                
                var row = '';
                row += '<tr>';
                row += '<td style="padding:2px">' + '  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checktabla">' + '</td>';
                row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + list[i].xx + '</td>';
                row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + list[i].xx + '</td>';
                row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + list[i].xx + '</td>';
                row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + list[i].xx + '</td>';
                row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + list[i].x + '</td>';
                row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + list[i].x + '</td>';
                row += '</tr>';


                $('#unidades').append(row);

            }
            var table = $('.table').DataTable({
                "dom": '<<t>ip>',
                "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                    $('ul.pagination').addClass("pagination-sm");
                },
                "bDestroy": true,
                "language": {
                    "decimal": "",
                    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
                    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
                    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
                    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
                    "infoPostFix": "",
                    "thousands": ",",
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing": "Procesando...",
                    "search": "Buscar:",
                    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "Primero",
                        "last": "Ultimo",
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                    }
                },
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Veo que no has dicho nada de mi respuesta. Si mi respuesta resuelve tu pregunta inicial te recomiendo la aceptes para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede abierta eternamente. Te paso un enlace donde explican como aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200 . En caso contrario puedes comentarme el problema que tengas al aplicarlo y ver si encuentro solución.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo esto debajo del done:

```
$('#unidades').empty();
```

O sea, que quede así:

```
.done(function (list) {
    $('#unidades').empty();
```